# How to check if the web page is submitted only 3 times?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have web form in which I have to make sure that 'SUBMIT' button is being clicked no more than 3 times. I have some logic in the form which restricts the user to enter anything after 3 failed attempts.

This is my logic, but I know this is not right:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    if (count <= 3) 
    {
        Function1();
    }
    else
        MessageBox("You submitted your information more than 3 times.");

}
```

This wont work because count will be ZERO every time the page refreshes up.

Comment: Do you need to reset the counter when redirected from the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the variable in the `ViewState` of the page. Initialize its value on the first load of the page:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.ViewState["Count"] = 0;
    }
}
```

On the `Button.Click` event increase the value of the count variable :

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{            
    Int32 count = Int32.Parse(this.ViewState["Count"].ToString()) + 1;
    this.ViewState["Count"] = count;
    if (count > 3)
    {
        // Do something ..
    }
}
```

Comment: The ViewState will be lost if the page is called by URL, Session will be more persistent (and Cookie even more).

Comment: @Olaf: The OP did not say anything about using the page multiple times .. He just said that the data will be submitted several times  ..

Comment: @klm9971: If you used the Session, why accept the Viewstate answer ;-) ?
@Akram: True, but still I'd go for the more global approach if there is no extra cost.

Comment: @Olaf: If the case is on the page level, then it's more appropriate to keep it on the page level... And I guess the OP have chosen my answer because of the logic, not the state variable type I used...

Answer (score 1):

You could store the count in a session variable.

```
int submitCount = 0;
if (Session["submitCount"] != null)
{
    submitCount = int.Parse (Session["submitCount"]);
}
// Code based on submitCount
Session["submitCount"] = ++submitCount; // Save # of submits to session
```

Comment: should I do it in global.asax?

Answer (score 0):

This'll work (not tested):

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["Clicked"] != null) 
        {
            int clicked = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Clicked"]) + 1;
            if(clicked == 3) 
            {
                MessageBox("You submitted your information more than 3 times.");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Clicked"] = clicked;
            }

        } 
        else
        {
            Session["Clicked"] = 1;
        }

        Function1();
    }
```

A Cookie will even be more persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Data does not persist across web requests, so you will need to store the count in some form of persistent storage.  You have several options: cookies, session variables, viewstate, database, etc.

A database is probably the most secure, since it's housed on the server and the user cannot tamper with it, but it also more work to set up.  The problem with session variables and view state is that, while they persist across web requests, they are not permanent, so the user will be able to submit a fourth request after the session has timed out.  Cookies have the same problem.

The important point is data is not retained across requests, so you'll have to research methods for adding persistent storage to your website and choose the solution that best matches your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also store the value in a hidden field.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSubmitCount" runat="server" Value="0" />

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count;
    if(!int.TryParse(hfSubmitCount.Value, out count))
        count = 0;
    count++;
    hfSubmitCount.Value = count.ToString();
    if (count <= 3)
        Function1();        
    else
        MessageBox("You submitted your information more than 3 times.");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know any asp.net but you should use session to keep the count of that.logic behind should be:

```
if (session variable do not exist)
 store session variable

else
 (increment session variable)
```

hope it helps

Comment: @Akram i just meant to help klm9971

Comment: I am not the one who voted down .. I was trying to warn you .. too late